# How to include groovy test-sources in generated jar or sources-jar using Maven

Tags: maven, unit-testing, groovy, gmaven-plugin

I'm using Maven with `gmaven` plugin. Also I use `maven-source-plugin` that allows me to generate `source.jar` containing my sources. Also I have groovy tests that reside in a standard src/test/groovy directory. I configured pom.xml so that tests run when I'm building my project. The problem is, I can't found how to include groovy tests sources into generated `-sources.jar` or at least in `myApp.jar` itself. As I see from here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Building+Groovy+Projects , 'groovy-jar' goal is marked as TODO. Please advise, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've googled "maven-sources-plugin add groovy sources" and found this.

http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/use-relative-Path-in-includes-and-excludes-of-maven-source-plugin-tp120913p120915.html

It worked.

Answer (score 2):

Usually a test-jar can be created by using the test-jar goal of the [maven-sources-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/test-jar-mojo.html) furthermore it will help you if you check the documentation of the [maven-sources-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/test-jar-mojo.html) in more detail to add the groovy sources into the sources-jar.